# How to easily refer to the index type of an associative array?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there an easy way to refer to the index type of an associative array in PLSQL while declaring a variable that represents its key?

I am looking for a language construct similar to the following one.

```
DECLARE
  i number;
  j i%type;
BEGIN
  null;
END;
```

I would like to be able to do something like that.

```
DECLARE
  type ty_my_type is table of number index by varchar2(4);
  my_array ty_my_type;
  -- key my_array.key%type;
  -- or
  -- key my_array%keytype;
BEGIN
  null;
END;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare a [`SUBTYPE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/datatypes.htm#i42580) and use that:

```
DECLARE
  SUBTYPE KEY_TYPE IS VARCHAR2(4);
  TYPE ASSOC_ARRAY_TYPE IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY KEY_TYPE;

  my_array ASSOC_ARRAY_TYPE;
  my_key   KEY_TYPE;
BEGIN
  NULL;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful because actually I refer to the index type using notation `table_name.column_name%type`. So defining a `SUBTYPE` works like some kind of an alias that's shorter.